# searching functionality using web api in mvc using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

i have a web api url with the help of that i have to find all the users according to the given distance of a zip in a search page for that i have implemented the concept using jquery ajax, i am facing some kind of problem its not working properly as soon as i hit submit button , but if i give it some time and hit the submit button then its working fine. what is the problem behind this. i am totaly confused can anyone here help me to sort out this problem .

```
@model App.ViewModels.ViewModelSearch
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Zip').on('focusout', function () {
                    getZipCodes();
                });

            $('#Distance').change(function () {
                getZipCodes();
            });
        });
        function getZipCodes() {
            var Options = "";
            var list = "";
 if (!$('#Zip').val() || !$('#Distance').val()) { return; }
            console.log("calling ajax function");
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "https://www.abcd.com/webservices/radius.php?key=eov4v4lbpjdaz73b&zip=" + $('#Zip').val() + " &radius=" + $('#Distance').val() + "&format=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("Inside success");
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
                            list += response.results[i].zip + ",";
                        }
                        list = list.substring(0, list.length - 1);          
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("Failure");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#ZipList').val(list);
                        console.log(list);
                    }
                });
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#Zip").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions")',
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "UserSearch", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAccountType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.AccountType, "Select AccountType")

                                    @Html.TextBox("FName", null, new { @class = "complete" })


                                    @Html.TextBox("LName", null, new { @class = "complete" })


                                    @Html.TextBox("Zip", null, new { @class = "complete" })

                                        <select name="Distance" id="Distance">
                                            <option value="0">Select Distance</option>
                                            <option value="1">1 Miles</option>
                                            <option value="2">2 Miles</option>
                                            <option value="3">3 Miles</option>
                                            <option value="4">4 Miles</option>
                                            <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
                                        </select>

                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ZipList)

                    <button type="submit" id="btn-gn">Find</button>

    }
```

Comment: events are all wrong. Nothing is bound to submit and `focusout` will trigger before autocomplete is selected. Doesn't seem you are doing proper validation in server code either or bad values wouldn't return any results

Comment: any idea sir can you please modify this, what you think is correct,i'll be very greatful.

Comment: @charlietfl sir i guess a delay function can be does the trick here on button click. no need of focusout here.